# How to read multiple rows in CSV file using selenium?

Tags: csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver, data-driven-tests

I want to perform datadriven testing using CSV file with multiple set of data.I'm using below code where it is reading only one row and remaining it is not reading,please anyone suggest or provide the exact code,how to read multiple set of rows from a csv file using selenium.

**Code:**

```
public class CSVdataread {

    WebDriver driver;
    String baseurl = "https://hploadrunnertutorial.blogspot.in/";   
    String CSV_file = "E:\\AppiumTutorials\\Selenium_Practice\\SeleniumYoutube\\TestData.csv";

    @BeforeClass
    public void openBrowser(){

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void verify_Search() throws InterruptedException{

        driver.get(baseurl);

        //Read CSV file
        CSVReader reader = null;
        try{
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(CSV_file));
            String[] cell=reader.readNext();

    while((cell= reader.readNext())!=null){

    for(int i=1;i<cell.length;i++){
        String keyword = cell[i];
        String emails = cell[1+i];
        String message=cell[2-i];
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-name")).sendKeys(keyword);
        System.out.println("System enters search keyword.");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email")).sendKeys(emails);
        System.out.println("System clears enter Search Keywords.");
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message")).sendKeys(message);
        driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-submit")).sendKeys(message);                        

                }

            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

**MY CSV file:**

```
SearchKeyword,Email,Message
Selenium Automation,rjeshqa19@gmail.com,testing message
Selenium WebDriver,,rajeshqa19@gmail.com,testingsecond message
```

Comment: could you pls accept the answer if you feel it's correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Also, I am not sure why you want a for loop. I assume you are not clicking on the "Send" button in the page. I edited few lines from your code. Also, ensure that you start the index from 0.

```
        driver.get(baseurl);

        // Read CSV file
        CSVReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(CSV_file));
            String[] cell = reader.readNext();
            while ((cell = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                int i = 0;
                String keyword = cell[i];
                String emails = cell[i + 1];
                String message = cell[i + 2];
                driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.sumome-welcomemat-action-close:nth-child(6)"));
                driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-name")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-name")).sendKeys(keyword);
                driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email")).sendKeys(emails);
                driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message")).clear();
                driver.findElement(By.id("ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message")).sendKeys(message);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```